# How do I do a check and run in the same Alloy execution?

Tags: alloy

I'm learning Alloy, and can use `check` and `run` individually.  But, when I have them both in, it seems that the `check` is ignored.  How do I execute both the `check` and the `run`?

To expand the question:

- If I have a `run`, do I even need a `check`? Won't it automatically check all my assertions? Or is the goal of the `check` not only to check the assertions, but to intentionally and exhaustively (within the scope) search for a counterexample?
- Is the goal of `run` only to find an instance that meets the predicate?  Or is there another usage of run?
- Perhaps `check` should be `search-counterexample` and `run` should be `search-example`?
- Is Alloy limited to one search (`check` or `run`) for execution? If so, is the best practice to simply comment out all but one check/run, and uncomment out one at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I execute both the check and the run?

You don't.  You do one at a time.

Given two predicates `P1` and `P2`, it's always possible to define a new predicate to combine them however you want (with `and`, `or`, `and not`, `=>`, etc., etc.), and doing so can be very helpful sometimes.

Given a predicate `P` and an assertion `A`, however, there may be less need to check them at the same time than you think.  If the assertion A holds for a given scope, then it holds whether predicate P is satisfied or not.  If it always holds in that scope, then you don't need to check it in addition to P, when seeking an instance of P.  (It will hold whether you check it or not.)

> - If I have a run, do I even need a check? Won't it automatically check all my assertions? Or is the goal of the check not only to check the assertions, but to intentionally and exhaustively (within the scope) search for a counterexample?

An assertion is checked only when you ask the Analyzer to check it.  The Analyzer checks the assertion precisely (and only) by looking for counter-examples.

In this, assertions differ from Alloy *facts*, which are always true by definition (or: by fiat) and need not be checked.  (And more than that: they *cannot* be checked:  since a counter-example is impossible, there is nothing for the Analyzer to look for, and there is no verb by means of which you could request that the Analyzer look for it.)

The difference between facts and assertions is worth thinking about.

Facts express constraints on a model; assertions don't.  Informally, an assertion can be thought of as a suggestion (or claim) that a given constraint is *already* imposed on the model, that it follows logically from what has already been said.  Assertions which state the blindingly obvious are useful, because checking them can draw our attention to situations where those blindingly obvious things are not in fact true.  Assertions which state non-obvious consequences of the constraints in a model are also useful, in a different way, drawing our attention as readers to consequences we might have overlooked.

Facts can be useful too, as simple ways to restrict the model to situations we are interested in.  But since they are always true, whether redundant with other constraints or not, facts have fewer opportunities to surprise us.  (The most frequent surprise I associate with facts is the unwelcome discovery that my formulation of a fact has made it impossible to find any instances of the model.  Over time, I have come to avoid using facts wherever possible:  anything I am tempted to write as a fact, I end up rewriting as a predicate.)

> - Is the goal of run only to find an instance that meets the predicate? Or is there another usage of run?

That's the only one this user of Alloy knows.

> - Perhaps check should be search-counterexample and run should be search-example?

You may have a point; `find-example` and `find-counterexample` might be clearer for new users. (I wouldn't like `search` here, at least not without `-for`.)  But some users' fingers may rebel at replacing a five-character command like `check` with a twenty-one-character equivalent.

> - Is Alloy limited to one search (check or run) for execution? If so, is the best practice to simply comment out all but one check/run, and uncomment out one at a time?

Not necessary; the Execute menu gives you your choice of the command to execute.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you saying that an `assert` can be false when I do a `run`? That is, Alloy will admit examples for a `run` that violate `assert`s? Or are you only saying that it won't actively look for counterexamples?

Comment: Yes, an `assert` can be false.  An assertion can be interpreted informally as a claim that the situation it describes will always hold, because it follows logically from the definition of the model.  Such a claim is not necessarily true, even if we believe it; that's why assertions are useful:  when we find counterexamples we learn something.  (For this reason, I very occasionally leave erroneous assertions standing, with a comment pointing out that they don't always hold.)  A `fact`, on the other hand, will always be true because it's *part of* the definition of the model and holds by fiat.